# How do I find the query parameters for a prepared statement in an oracle .trc file?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, debugging

I have an oracle query generating a 3137 error, and the trace file contains the query. 
For example:

```
select x from y where z = :1
```

I think it would help to isolate the problem if I could determine the specific value of :1, however the 4.7M file doesn't seem to offer that information.

Is this information stored in the trc file?

This is oracle 11g running on redhat.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the .trc file [described here](http://www.oracle-wiki.net/startdocsreallifereadingoracletracefiles) is made the same way yours was, but this might help you.

Essentially, somewhere in there, there should be a section of Binds which shows which values were bound to that :1 variable.  The article doesn't do a good job of explaining how to tell which binds went to which queries since the example had only one query (and I can't figure it out from looking at it).  Ignore the `sort|uniq` bit they used at the end to show that it was always the same query over and over, and you should get results like

```
Bind#0
  value=55
```

or whatever.

Comment: The tie in between a statement and the binds is the cursor number. In the link description the statement is seen in PARSING IN CURSOR #2 and the binds in BINDS #2. But the same cursor number may get reused by the session as cursors are closed and opened.

Comment: @Gary thanks for the cursor hint, I do see many cursor notes, but am still not able to tie them to a bind variable.

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking out the [Trace Analyzer](http://awads.net/wp/2006/07/18/oracle-trace-analyzer-is-tkprof-on-steroids/) if you have an Oracle support contract.

Comment: this looks good, the poster intimates that the bind variables may not be availble in the trc.

Answer (score 0):

### Source of the problem

If the trace (.trc) file is missing **Bind Variable values** (or Parameter values in a OracleCommand in ODP.NET for example) this is due to the way the trace has been started.

If you use one of the following commands as the [Using Application Tracing Tools](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#i4183) page states:

```
ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE = TRUE;

EXEC DBMS_SESSION.set_sql_trace(sql_trace => TRUE);
```

..you are **not** recording bind values!

### Solution

To record bind variable values there are other, alternative ways, to start the trace depending on your Database version and loaded packages.
If you are on Oracle 10g+ the easiest way is to use the following command to start the trace:

```
DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE)
```

Here is the complete list of available commands to start the trace with bind variables recording (source: [SQL trace, 10046, trcsess and tkprof in Oracle 10g](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/sql-trace-10046-trcsess-and-tkprof-10g.php)):

```
-- All versions.
ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';

EXEC DBMS_SYSTEM.set_ev(si=>123, se=>1234, ev=>10046, le=>4, nm=>' ');

-- All versions, requires DBMS_SUPPORT package to be loaded.
EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace(waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE);
EXEC DBMS_SUPPORT.start_trace_in_session(sid=>123, serial=>1234, waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE);

-- Oracle 10g
EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE);

EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.session_trace_enable(session_id =>1234, serial_num=>1234, binds=>TRUE, binds=>TRUE);

EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.client_id_trace_enable(client_id=>'tim_hall', waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE);

EXEC DBMS_MONITOR.serv_mod_act_trace_enable(service_name=>'db10g', module_name=>'test_api', action_name=>'running', -
> waits=>FALSE, binds=>TRUE);
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it was still unanswered, and I just had the same problem: I had the trace file, but it was missing _Bind#whatever_ information (as per Nathan Feger question).
After some googling I finally found the solution, and thought it was good to answer the question, in the hope it helps someone having the same problem.